# Variable does not exist within Symfony Form Theme block override

Tags: symfony, twig

I am building a form which contains a series of categories used to search some content, defined as a ChoiceType within my Symfony FormType.

I pass the category list along with some other data (per-category count) (defined as the variable "aggs" in my controller) into a Twig template and create a form theme, overriding the choice_widget_options block for my categories drop-down so that I can display the extra data at render time, thus:

```
{% form_theme form.categories _self %}
{% block choice_widget_options %}
    {% if choices is defined %}
        {% for choice in choices %}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}">{{ choice.label }} {{ aggs }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock choice_widget_options %}
```

Why is it that my block here cannot access the top-level variables defined in my controller? It can see the "app" global variable, but not the controller-defined ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I can do this in my controller: "$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('aggs', 'somevalue')" but this feels rather inelegant and I'd like to understand _why_ I can't access this directly

Comment: Could it be that you've placed the form rendering inside a macro?

Answer (score 1):

More elegant solution is to override the **buildView** method of AbstractType class.

Just add:

```
$view->vars[‘aggs’] = YOUR AGGS VAR;
```

And the use it in your form as:

```
<option value="{{ choice.value }}">{{ choice.label }} {{ form.vars.aggs }}</option>
```

Basically you pass the variable to your form and then you use it in twig. The way you pass it to the form type is up to you. It can be a dependency injection or via the form options from the controller.